# Habilitar div apos x horas javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp

Sinceramente não se é possivel fazer isso via codigo mas...

Entao tenho uma div com um formulario, que deve ser habilitada para preenchimento do usuario somente apos 400h que a 1ª parte deste formulario (outra div) foi finalizada, quando esta div for habilitada tenho que disparar um email avisando o cliente que agora ela esta disponivel.

Comment: Quer dizer: o usuário entra no site preenche algo, ai ele clica em "Enviar!". Depois ele fecha o browser, vai dar um passeio de 400h depois ele recebe um e-mail dizendo para ele entrar novamente no site para preencher a próxima informação. Seria isso?

Comment: Sem entrar nos detalhes (pois não tenho experiência com ASP), minha sugestão é o seguinte: 1) salvar a data e hora que a primeira parte foi preenchida, e agendar uma tarefa para executar o código que envia o e-mail conforme a data futura calculada; 2) sempre que o usuário requisitar aquele formulário (se ele já tiver o link), veja a data/hora salva no banco e calcule se ele já pode acessá-lo ou não; 3) caso ele possa vê-lo mas não respondê-lo, você pode fazer esse controle com JavaScript, mas *sempre validando no lado do servidor* se a ação ocorreu no intervalo de tempo correto.